# connecting to a database via tsql on mac 10.10.4

Tags: sql-server, connectivity, mac-os-x

I'm trying to connect to a database via tsql.

I use the following command:

`TDSVER=8.0 tsql -S <server IP> -p 1433 -U <my username> -P <my password>`

Now, I know the server IP is correct because I can ping it. I also know the port is correct from `tsql -LH`. It tells me the tcp is 1433.

However, when I connect the log shows:

```
log.c:196:Starting log file for FreeTDS 0.91.103
    on 2015-07-01 14:35:39 with debug flags 0x4fff.
iconv.c:330:tds_iconv_open(0x7fca62700310, UTF-8)
iconv.c:187:local name for ISO-8859-1 is ISO-8859-1
iconv.c:187:local name for UTF-8 is UTF-8
iconv.c:187:local name for UCS-2LE is UCS-2LE
iconv.c:187:local name for UCS-2BE is UCS-2BE
iconv.c:349:setting up conversions for client charset "UTF-8"
iconv.c:351:preparing iconv for "UTF-8" <-> "UCS-2LE" conversion
iconv.c:391:preparing iconv for "ISO-8859-1" <-> "UCS-2LE" conversion
iconv.c:394:tds_iconv_open: done
net.c:205:Connecting to **<edited for security>** port 4000 (TDS version 7.1)
net.c:270:tds_open_socket: connect(2) returned "Operation now in progress"
net.c:306:getsockopt(2) reported: Connection refused
net.c:316:tds_open_socket() failed
util.c:331:tdserror(0x7fca62700260, 0x7fca62700310, 20009, 61)
util.c:361:tdserror: client library returned TDS_INT_CANCEL(2)
util.c:384:tdserror: returning TDS_INT_CANCEL(2)
mem.c:615:tds_free_all_results()
```

Why does it resort to port 4000? When I specifically specify 1433? Also, when I do tsql -C it tell me version 5.0 when I specifically edited /opt/local/etc/freetds to use 8.0?

This has been driving me nuts!